# jQuery SOAP header

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

i have a secured web service which issues a token if authentication is successful and everything works fine on a c#.net page. the issue i am having is i want to access the service calls from jQuery.

How can i access / modify / or even add a SOAP header in jQuery call. my custom SOAP header class header is as follows:

```
public class SecuredWebServiceHeader : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    public string AuthenticatedToken;
}
```

i tired beforeSend in $.ajax like

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '<%=GetToken()%>');
                        },
```

but the web service does not see the header all.

any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: servicename + "/" + functionName,
    contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        SOAPAction: 'Your service'
    },
    data: 'Your  full SoapHeader Here',
    success: successFn,
    error: errorFn
});
```

For details go through [Jeferry To's Reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933782/send-a-custom-header-of-soap-envelope-using-jquery-ajax)

Get additional help below:

**[Jquery Soap header](http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/)**

**[JavaScript Soap Header](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11404133/edit)**

Comment: this is not working, because the service still cannot see the header

Comment: Have you tried other link i have given..I am sure you will get your solution.

Comment: It seems those links discuss SOAP services, the scenario I have is that I want to pass a an authentication token in the header but the service methods return JSON data? 

Any ideas how header info can be sent in Jquery Ajax call to Fetch JSON data.